# while rendering animation the mirrored part by mirror modifier is not showing in the output(to MPEG)...help?

Tags: mesh

title says it all.i made a simple mesh using mirror and animated it but while animating using defaults only the original half is showing up not the one which is mirrored by blender.help will be appreciated,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you accidentally turned the modifier off for rendering?

[image]